# double integral problem(application of Fubini/Toneli?)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose for that $k:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $$\sup_x\int|k(x,y)|dy<\infty, \ \ \ \sup_y\int|k(x,y)|dx<\infty$$
how would you show that $\iint k^2(x,y)dydx$ is finite?

Any idea/hints?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is true.  Consider $k(x,y) = e^{-(x-y)^2}$.